# Omniauth /auth/facebook/callback.json - request.env["omniauth.auth"] is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

To be specific:

My Rails app works perfectly if i call

`/auth/facebook/callback` or `/auth/facebook/callback?format=json`

but when i try to call

`/auth/facebook/callback.json`

there is no `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` (it's nil)

Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: I had a similar issue to this recently, where this error occurred with  twitter/omniauth. The issue was that I had upgraded my devise gem, but not omniauth-twitter. Perhaps that may fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because the .json extension for a url means you have either a .json view for this method or will respond with json format.

While this should be handle by omniauth in a redirect... it cannot work.